# Dynamically change WTForms field type between SelectField and HiddenField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a WTForms field (value_currency) that I want to sometimes be a SelectField and sometimes a HiddenField. I use the same view and template for a page that both creates new items and edits existing items. If I load the page to create a new item, I want this field to be a SelectField, and if I load the page to edit an existing item, I want this field to be a HiddenField because it's a non-editable field.

Here is what I have so far:

FORM

```
class PromoForm(Form):
    value = StringField('value')
    currencies = Currency.query.order_by(Currency.id).all()
    currency_choices = []
    for currency in currencies:
        currency_choice = (currency.id, currency.name)
        currency_choices.append(currency_choice)
    value_currency = SelectField('value_currency', choices=currency_choices)
```

VIEW

```
@app.route('/promo/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def promo(id):
    form = PromoForm()
    # Existing promo will pass in its id
    # id = 0 if a new promo is to be created
    if id != str(0):
        # Load existing promo
        promo = Promo.query.get(id)
        # display value in decimal format
        form.value.default = "{0}.{1:0>2}".format(
            promo.value_cents//100, promo.value_cents%100)
        form.process()
        return render_template('promo.html', promo=promo, form=form)
    else:
        # New promo
        audit_log('GET', client, session=session)
        return render_template('promo.html', form=form)
```

TEMPLATE

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if promo is defined %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('.promo', id=promo.id) }}" method="post">
    {% else %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('.promo', id=0) }}" method="post">
    {% endif %}
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div>
        <label for="value">Promo Value</label>
        {% if promo is defined %}
            {{ form.value() }}
        {% else %}
            {{ form.value() }}
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in form.value.errors %}
            <span class="error">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if promo is defined %}
            # ----> Promo.value_currency should be a hidden field here (Doesn't work)
            {{ promo.value_currency }}
        {% else %}
            # ----> Promo.value_currency is a select field here (Currently works)
            {{ form.value_currency() }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="submit_btn">
        {% if promo is defined %}
            <input type="submit" value="Update Promo">
        {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Create Promo">
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I know I can just simply hardcode the hidden input element and drop in the value with Jinja, but I prefer to do it with WTForms and not do any form element hard coding. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not just omit the field from the template when editing a record?

Comment: It seems WTForms doesn't like that, since it is part of the form. When I did that, the form page would simply refresh on submit and form.validate_on_submit == False so the update doesn't get processed.

Answer (score 5):

See (duplicated) question: [Flask, WTForms: Is there a way to make a StringField in the form _temporarily_ hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988970/flask-wtforms-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-stringfield-in-the-form-temporarily-h).

You cannot just *omit* the field, and you cannot change its object type (from SelectField to HiddenField) either.

However, you can change its *widget* object dynamically.
Replace this with a `HiddenInput`.

```
from wtforms.widgets import HiddenInput

class PromoForm(Form):
    value = StringField('value')
    currencies = Currency.query.order_by(Currency.id).all()
    currency_choices = []
    for currency in currencies:
        currency_choice = (currency.id, currency.name)
        currency_choices.append(currency_choice)
    value_currency = SelectField('value_currency', choices=currency_choices)
    
    def hide_value_currency(self, value):
        """
        Hide the value_currency field by morping it into a 
        HiddenInput.    
        """ 
        self.value_currency.widget = HiddenInput()
        # wtforms chokes if the data attribute is not present
        self.value_currency.data = value
        # wtforms chokes on SelectField with HiddenInput widget
        # if there is no _data() callable
        self.value_currency._value = lambda: value
```

Call `form.hide_value_currency(pre_set_value)` in your view when required.

No logic in your template necessary.

Comment: great workaround. OP should mark this as the accepted answer.