# Flask, WTForms: Is there a way to make a StringField in the form _temporarily_ hidden?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

This is my model:

```
class F(Form):
    a = StringField('a', validators = [validators.DataRequired()])
```

Is there a way to make a StringField in the form temporarily hidden? Something like:

```
@app.route('/f', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def f():
    form = F(request.form)
    if foo(form):
        form.a.__MakeTemporarilyHidden__()
    else:
        form.a.__MakeItVisibleAgain__()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('f.html', form = form)
```

I am aware of wtforms.fields.HiddenField but I want to dynamically switch between StringField and HiddenField and back.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407564/dynamically-change-wtforms-field-type-between-selectfield-and-hiddenfield .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
class F(Form):
    a = StringField('a', validators = [validators.DataRequired()])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        hide_a = kwargs.pop('hide_a')
        super(F, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hide_a:
            self.a.widget = widgets.HiddenInput()

@app.route('/f', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def f():
    if foo():
        form = F(request.form, hide_a=True)
    else:
        form = F(request.form)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('f.html', form = form)
```

Although it can be done in views too like you did, but it is better to keep form logic in your Form class.

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting  "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HiddenField'"

Comment: Yeah, sorry! my bad, it is `HiddenInput`. Edited!

Comment: Thanks. It works but foo() actually depends on form, so I edited my question saying "if foo(form):". Is there a way to hide/unhide fields not in a constructor?

Comment: @Digital you can do `self.a.widget = widgets.HiddenInput()` in your view in place of `form.a.__MakeTemporarilyHidden__()` and it should work same as it works from constructor.

Comment: Many thanks. That's all I wanted and, please correct me if I am wrong, I do not need that constructor any more.

Comment: Yes, If you do `form.a.widget = widgets.HiddenInput()` in your view method, then you wouldn't need the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Af far as I've found, it's not a good idea to change the field to a HiddenField.

What you can do however is to leave the field as it is, but replace its *widget* so that it's rendered as hidden.  The relevant widget is `wtforms.widgets.HiddenInput`.

Note: this was done on Python3.

Extend your form class with a `hide_a()` method (what you were calling `__MakeTemporarilyHidden__`):

```
from wtforms.widgets import HiddenInput

class F(Form):
    a = StringField('a', validators = [validators.DataRequired()])

def hide_a(self):
    a.widget = HiddenInput()
```

You might need to set `a.data` to a certain value.  If the field is a `SelectField`, you might even need to add a `_value` callable to the field.